# How do you give two routers access to a network device? (Network drawing included)

Tags: networking, router, routing, vlan

[Network Drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aaxmk.png)

I want "House LAN" and "Computer A" both to have access to the surveillance camera. How is this done?

I was considering creating two VLANs on "Dual WAN Router A":

VLAN_A: Port 3 and Port 4

VLAN_B: Port 5 and Port 4

This way, the "House LAN" and "Computer A" will remain isolated from each other, which is also a requirement.

Naturally, I will also create a static route on "Dual WAN Router A" to route traffic from "Computer A" onto subnet 192.168.1.x, where the surveillance camera resides.

Does my approach make sense? Will this work?

Comment: You cannot assign the same port (port 4) to two VLANs as client port.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably solve this by port forwarding. In your case, you would need it on both routers.

For example, router B could forward inbound traffic to router A if that traffic is directed to the camera; such traffic can easily be identified by the destination IP address and port. Using the same method, router A could forward the respective inbound traffic to the camera.

These steps make sure that machines in the House LAN have access to the camera. As I understand your drawing, Computer A already has access to the camera (I strongly assume that router A as usual also acts as a switch in that it connects P1, P2, P3, P4, P5 as a normal switch would do).

All routers I have seen in the last years offer that type of port forwarding. VLAN based solutions may be safer in some situations, but whether or not this is true in your case is impossible to tell without knowing much more details (e.g. who has physical access or management access to which device, who has physical access to network sockets, to the cables and so on).

Answer (score 0):

1. Set up appropriate static routes so that everything can reach everything else.
2. Test to make sure every device can reach every other device.
3. Add firewall rules to block any traffic you don't want.
4. Test to make sure that the rules block the traffic that they are supposed to block.

I don't recommend using absence of routes or wrong routes as a security scheme. It's too complex and unreliable. That's what firewall rules are for.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I suppose I'm a little confused though. Are you saying the VLANs are not required at all and what I'm trying to achieve can be done with only the appropriate static routes?

Comment: @user3751044 I would recommend using VLANs to form the separate IP networks and keep separate networks in separate broadcast domains. Then use static routes to make all the traffic work. Then firewalling to block unwanted traffic.

Comment: Thanks again for the confirmation. I was a little confused because somebody on the original post replied that you can't have two VLANs on the same port.